# Onion Architecture with I18N Database Driven Internationalization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization, onion-architecture

I can't find an answer anywhere really so thought I would post a question about it.

I have followed this tutorial [ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization · How to Store Strings in a Database or Xml](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx)

Now that is fine and all, I can get it to work.

The question now is, how to properly incorporate that into the [Onion Architecture](https://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture).

The tutorial has a `Resource` Project. Is that still valid or can that be abstracted out?

There is just not a good tutorial on how to incorporate internationalization into the Onion Architecture.

What I have so far is:

- Database Table (Resource) which holds {Name, Culture, Type, Value}
- Entity called `Resource`
- Interface called 'IResourceRepository` (GetResources(), GetResource(Culture,Name))
- I have a Service Interface and a Service which also has the same methods as the Repository to get me the resource.

It's my first Time setting up a brand new web application, and only recently learned about the Onion Architecture. Any Help will be very much appreciated.

**Update**

Here is my partial attempt.

Correct me If i'm wrong please.

- App.Domain.Entities

  - Resource.cs (name, culture, type, value)
- App.Domain.Interfaces

  - IResourceRepository.cs (GetResources(), GetResource(Culture, Name))
- App.Infrastructure.Data

  - ResourceRepository.cs (GetResources(), GetResource(Culture, Name))
- App.Services.Interfaces

  - IResourceService.cs (object GetResource(Culture, Name))
- App.Web.UI.Services

  - BaseResourceService.cs (Implements IResourceService.cs)
  - ResourceService.cs (Extends BaseResourceService.cs)

This is how for I got so far. So `Resource` contains a whole bunch of resources for different cultures.

Pretty sure 'n have done something wrong tho.

Comment: Do any of your domain services need `ResourceEntry`? If not, everything should move to the `Infrastructure` layer of your Onion architecture.

Comment: 'Domain Services' ? Not sure what you mean. It basically is a whole lot of resources stored in the database, then i retrieve it and set properties in the UI based on the Culture selected and Property Name available to internationalize. please wee update to question, that is what I have attempted, any feedback / alternative solution will be much appreciated

Comment: Domain services are what your business is all about. I mean, if the business of your application is to deal with Resources, then all the business logic should be coded in the Doamin layer. That means that your `App.Services.Interfaces` should be in the Domain layer and its implementation as well!

Comment: An example of what the application can do is. Add a new user to the system. But i want to provide the ability to do that in a number of cultures. so I save all those cultures in the resource table/entity. I use the repo and its interface to pull the data out of the database. I use the service and it's interface deal with caching and validation of the resource. The service gets injected into the UI layer. Repo gets injected into the service layer. I followed this architecture, well hope I did. https://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture

Comment: So you're application business seems to be user management, not dealing with resoources. Your business code should be about user management, right?. The question is: do you need to access resources while, let's say, instering a new user in the system? You somehow answered that question saying that your `IResourceService` is implemented by the UI layer. From my point of view, all the resources related code should be inside the `Infrastrucure` layer, not in the `Domain`. Make sense?